# Is it possible to detect if a class has a member function regardless of return type with Boost TTI

Tags: c++, boost, introspection

Browsing though the examples in the Boost TTI library, I only find example where the return type is specified.

Is it possible to utilize Boost TTI to see if a class has a specified member function, regardless of it's parameters and return value?

I'd like something like this:

```
struct BigBear {
  auto roar() -> int {return 1;}
};
struct SmallBear {
  auto roar() const -> float {return 0.0f;}
};
struct Duck {
  auto quack() {}
};

BOOST_TTI_HAS_MEMBER_FUNCTION(roar);
static_assert(has_member_function_roar<BigBear>::value, "")
static_assert(has_member_function_roar<SmallBear>::value, "")
static_assert(!has_member_function_roar<Duck>::value, "")
```

Comment: It is possible with [`std::is_detected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected).

Comment: Hehe did you also see that Marshall Clow presentation?